# Gödels incompleteness theorem false for natural numbers

Tags: peano-axioms, incompleteness, nonstandard-models

Do I understand it correctly that in an axiomatic system that includes the natual numbers defined by using Peano's axiom, where the 9th axiom (induction) is formulated using 2nd-order logic, then
Gödels incompleteness theorem is false ?

Can I say that if an axiomatic system defines the natural numbers properly (i.e. not allowing non-standard models), then Gödels incompleteness theorem will be false ?

Why do mathematicians accept axiomatic systems for the natural numbers, such as Peano arithmetic, which allow non-standard models ? If the axioms allow for multiple non-isomorphic models, then we are missing some axiom. Or am I throwing babies out with bathwater having this attitude ?

Comment: The natural numbers are not "defined by axioms." And why would you think 2nd order logic would solve the problem? The point of Gödel is that any recursively enumerable (aka useful to humans) axiom system which can encode the first order Peano axiom system will also be incomplete.

Comment: In second-order logic, Gödel's incompleteness theorems are meaningless. These theorems  are about provability, but there is no adequate notion of proof in second-order logic.

Comment: @AndreasBlass are you saying that one cannot construct proofs based on second-order axioms ? or is it just Gödel numbering of proofs that breaks down ?

Comment: @AxelBregnsbo What second-order axioms? And why? Keep in mind that the set of valid sentences of second-order logic is nowhere near computably enumerable --- it's well beyond the projective hierarchy. And the continuum hypothesis (undecidable in ZFC) can be expressed as a sentence of second-order logic. (Gödel numbering, on the other hand, is not a problem at all.)